# Woocommerce : How to remove product lines on Checkout page?

Tags: woocommerce

Like in cart, how could i do to be able to remove product in Checkout page with a 'x' link ?

Is there any hook do to that  ?

thanks

Comment: The "remove" X links are there by default. Maybe try switching themes.

Comment: do you mean in checkout page too ?

Comment: sorry but i tried with WP default and there is no "remove" X links on checkout page...

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I was thinking of the cart page. The point of the checkout is you are ready to check out, no? And in theory, should not be making adjustments to the cart.

Comment: so do you think it's not possible ?

Comment: I mean, 97% of WordPress things are possible given enough time and/or resources. It's just up to you to decide whether that time/resource commitment is worth the benefit gained.

Comment: is this what you are looking.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42548276/adding-a-custom-text-under-the-x-button-that-removes-items-from-cart/42551148#42551148

Answer (score 12):

I was confronted to the same problem, and couldn't find a way to solve it on Google. So i tried by myself and found this solution :

1. **Overriding woocommerce order review on checkout page in your theme :**

   - Create a folder in your theme, named 'woocommerce', then create a child folder named 'checkout' in there.
   - Copy the review-order.php file from the woocommerce folder *(plugins/woocommerce/templates/checkout)* in your new checkout folder.
     This new review-order.php file will override the default template.
2. **Adding the remove x button for each product on the checkout page :**

On the new review-order.php *(yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout)* :

- Add `<th class="product-remove"><?php _e( 'Remove', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>` in the head of the shop table.
- Copy from the default cart.php file (l. 49) *(plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart)*

```php
<td class="product-remove">
    <?php
        echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">&times;</a>',
                esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_id() ),
                esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
            ),
            $cart_item_key
        );
    ?>
</td>
```

- Paste it in the body of the shop table.

I hope this will be helpful as it is my first answer on StackOF,
It has done the job for me, but it may not be the best way to proceed.

Looking forward to new answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

The function function ns_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item hooks into woocommerce_cart_item_name filter, which allows to change the output and add a link (the cross icon) around the product item name. The link we add is based on WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) function, which creates an url for specified cart item key.

Add the code below to your theme’s functions.php file.

```
function ns_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item( $product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
if ( is_checkout() ) {
    $_product = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
    $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

    $remove_link = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" class="remove" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s">×</a>',
        esc_url( WC()->cart->get_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
        __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_attr( $product_id ),
        esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
    ), $cart_item_key );

    return '<span>' . $remove_link . '</span> <span>' . $product_name . '</span>';
}

return $product_name;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'ns_woocommerce_checkout_remove_item', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This doesnt work anymore in May 2023